# Entity Framework 6 foreign key

Tags: database, model, foreign-keys, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am coding an MVC5 internet application with EF6, and have a question in regards to a foreign key name.

I have a model called `MapLocationList` that has these two fields:

```
public int mapLocationListGalleryId { get; set; }
public virtual MapLocationListGallery mapLocationListGallery { get; set; }
```

When EF creates the table, there is both the following columns:

- mapLocationListGalleryId
- MapLocationListGallery_Id

Can someone please explain why there are two columns for the `MapLocationListGallery` foreign key?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have changed the name to use an uppercase M, yet the additional column is still there.

Here is my model:

```
public class MapLocationList : IMapLocationItemWithAssets
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string mapLocationItemType { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime creationDate { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime lastUpdate { get; set; }
    public string thumbnailDisplayText { get; set; }
    public bool parentIsMapLocation { get; set; }
    public int thumbnailAssetId { get; set; }
    public virtual Asset thumbnailAsset { get; set; }
    public int mapLocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual MapLocation mapLocation { get; set; }
    public int mapLocationListGalleryId { get; set; }
    public virtual MapLocationListGallery mapLocationListGallery { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MapLocationListItem> listItems { get; set; }

    public MapLocationList()
    {
        creationDate = DateTime.Now;
        lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        listItems = new List<MapLocationListItem>();
    }
}
```

I also have the following in the `OnModelCreating` function:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MapLocationListGallery>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.thumbnailAsset)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<MapLocationList>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.thumbnailAsset)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<MapLocationList>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.mapLocationListGallery)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<MapLocationListItem>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.thumbnailAsset)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach as well and I do not experience this behavior. Probably you need to rename your properties to CamelCase (note the capital M):

```
public int MapLocationListGalleryId { get; set; }
public virtual MapLocationListGallery MapLocationListGallery { get; set; }
```

If that doesn't help take a look at the `ForeignKeyAttribute` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856218/understanding-foreignkey-attribute-in-entity-framework-code-first).

**Edit**

I'm not familiar with the fluent api, but I think you could try to set the foreign key explicitly using something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MapLocationList>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.mapLocationListGallery)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.mapLocationListGalleryId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

For more info see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx), topic: "Configuring Unconventional Foreign Key Names". Although it's strange this is necessary because your code seems to comply with the Code First convention (with capital M, i.e. the class name).

Comment: I have added some additional information in my post.