# ihave an error with making composite key from two foreign key references to two different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

ihave 3 models user,ArticleComments and UserSubsription .. im trying to make 3 prop as composite key and two of them are foreign key references to two different tables but i got error while trying to enable-migrations

User.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebAppInternetApp.Models;

namespace WebAppInternetApp.Models
{
    public class User
    {

        public User()
        {
            this.WriterIDs = new HashSet<JobArticle>();
            this.AdminIDs = new HashSet<JobArticle>();
            this.UserIDs = new HashSet<ArticleComments>();
            this.UserIDss = new HashSet<UserQuestion>();
            this.UseerIDsss = new HashSet<UserSubscription>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int UID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string FName { set; get; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string LName { set; get; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { set; get; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 8)]
        public string Password { set; get; }

        [Required]
        public bool Status { set; get; }

        [Required]
        [Phone]
        public string PhoneNo { set; get; }

        [Column(TypeName = "image")]
        public byte[] UserImg { set; get; }

        public virtual ICollection<JobArticle> WriterIDs { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<JobArticle> AdminIDs { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<ArticleComments> UserIDs { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserQuestion> UserIDss { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserSubscription> UseerIDsss { set; get; }

        public virtual UserType usertypeIDs { set; get; }



    }
}
```

Article Comments.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebAppInternetApp.Models
{
    public class ArticleComments
    {
        [Required]
        public string Comment { set; get; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public DateTime CommentTime { set; get; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public virtual User UserID { set; get; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [ForeignKey("JobArticle")]
        public virtual JobArticle ArticleID { set; get; }
    }
}
```

UserSubsription.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebAppInternetApp.Models;

namespace WebAppInternetApp.Models
{
    public class UserSubscription
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public virtual User UserIDs { set; get; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("JobCategory")]
        public virtual JobCategory SubscriptID { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ArticleID' on type 'WebAppInternetApp.Models.ArticleComments' is not valid. The foreign key name 'JobArticle' was not found on the dependent type 'WebAppInternetApp.Models.ArticleComments'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Answer (score 0):

Base on Microsoft [description of the ForeignKeyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If you add the ForeigKey attribute to a foreign key property, you
>   should specify the name of the associated navigation property. If you
>   add the ForeigKey attribute to a navigation property, you should
>   specify the name of the associated foreign key(s). If a navigation
>   property has multiple foreign keys, use comma to separate the list of
>   foreign key names

In your code, you don't define the foreign key property.  You only define the navigation properties.

Check this article to see how to use the ForeignKey attribute:

[Understanding ForeignKey attribute in entity framework code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856218/understanding-foreignkey-attribute-in-entity-framework-code-first)

For example, your UserSubscription should look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebAppInternetApp.Models;

namespace WebAppInternetApp.Models
{
    public class UserSubscription
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int UserIDs { set; get; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("JobCategory")]
        public int SubscriptID { set; get; }

        // those are the navigation properties
        public virtual User User { set; get; }
        public virtual JobCategory JobCategory { set; get; }
    }
}
```

And ArticleComments could be like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebAppInternetApp.Models
{
    public class ArticleComments
    {
        [Required]
        public string Comment { set; get; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public DateTime CommentTime { set; get; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int UserID { set; get; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [ForeignKey("JobArticle")]
        public int ArticleID { set; get; }

        public virtual User User { set; get; }
        public virtual JobArticle JobArticle { set; get; }

    }
}
```

Comment: if i delete foreign keys i got this message "WebAppInternetApp.Models.UserSubscription: : EntityType 'UserSubscription' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
UserSubscriptions: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserSubscriptions' is based on type 'UserSubscription' that has no keys defined.
"

Comment: but it will make two property for userid and article id !

Comment: and i got this message while trying this 

WebAppInternetApp.Models.UserSubscription: : EntityType 'UserSubscription' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
UserSubscriptions: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserSubscriptions' is based on type 'UserSubscription' that has no keys defined.